# Unable to Access DynamoDB through API Gateway

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am making a React Web App with AWS Amplify. When I attempt to invoke my ANY method integration as GET, returns a 404 error in the console. But the body of the error response is: '''Cannot GET /createleave'''

The POST method works and updates my DynamoDB table with an object and its items. I want to be able to call a specific object from my table, but I am confused by the error I am receiving. My code for the GET method is below.

```
getLeave = event => {
    API.get('apiName', '/createleave').then(response => {

        this.setState(state => ({
            leaveDetails: response,
        }));

        console.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
    });
}
```

It should return a requested object from the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There was an error in the default AWS Amplify lambda code,  and it required adding a new function above all of the other functions. [api.get function](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1857)